# How to set up a one-off job trigger at a specified time using Grails Quartz2 plugin

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am using [Quartz2 Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2), and am trying to dynamically trigger a very simple job. When the user performs a certain action, the job should be triggered some certain number of minutes in the future, and only run once.

I have tried using the simple 'schedule' method that takes a date and job data:

```
def sendTime = new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    sendTime = sendTime + (connectionInstance.timeout).minutes
    println "I will send the job at $sendTime"
}
ReportSmssyncTimeoutJob.schedule(sendTime, [connectionId:params.id])
```

In this setup, I find that the job actually triggers immediately instead of waiting until 'sendTime'.

My second attempt, after looking at the plugin source, was to use a SimpleTrigger

```
def sendTime = new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    sendTime = sendTime + (connectionInstance.timeout).minutes
    println "I will send the job at $sendTime"
}
// arguments here are: jobKey='test', startTime=sendTime, repeatCount=0, repeatInterval=1 (zero not allowed), job-arguments)
def trigger = TriggerHelper.simpleTrigger(new JobKey("test"), sendTime, 0, 1, [connectionId:params.id])
ReportSmssyncTimeoutJob.schedule(trigger)
```

In this setup, the job also triggers immediately. Is there something wrong with the SimpleTrigger implementation which prevents it from waiting until startDate?

Unfortunately, switching to the main 'quartz' plugin (which now has support for Quartz 2) is not an option as I am working on a project that has loads of jobs set up to work with the quartz2 plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this on the Grails mailing list and got the answer: this is a bug in the quartz2 plugin. It should be fixed in the next release (bug was noted in 0.2.3).

Update: tested this in v2.1.6.2 of the quartz2 plugin, and can confirm that both of the approaches in my question now work.